# Argument of type 'number[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<number>'

Tags: d3.js, typescript3.0

I am building a scatter plot using typescript and d3js.

The tsconfig is quite strong in terms of constraints.

The error is linked to the variable: **data**

### Error

> Argument of type 'number[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike'.
>     Index signatures are incompatible.
>       Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)

### scatterPlot.ts

```js
    /*jshint esversion: 6 */

    /// <reference path="twikey.interfaces.ts" />

    function scatterPlot(placeholder : HTMLDivElement) {
        let data : number[][] = [[5, 3], [10, 17], [15, 4], [2, 8]];
   ...    
        let datax = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max<number>(data, function (d : number[]) : number {
                return d![0];
            })])
            .range([0, width]);       
    ...

    }
```

### tsconfig.json

```
    {
        "compileOnSave": true,
        "compilerOptions": {
            "allowJs": false,
            "declaration": true,
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "module": "es6",
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "noImplicitAny": true,
            "outDir": "wwwroot/dist/js",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "strictNullChecks": true,
            "target": "es6"
        },
        "files": [
            "wwwroot/src/drawLineChart.ts",
            "wwwroot/src/twikey.api.ts",
            "wwwroot/src/scatterPlot.ts"
        ],
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "dist"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have misplaced the casting "d3.max`<number>`" -> "`<number>`d3.max"

```
    let datax = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, <number>d3.max(data, function (d : number[]) : number {
            return d[0];
        })])
```